# Stretching content to fit desktop page using css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How do I stretch this content to fit full page width in desktop?

Html:

```
<div class="entry-content">
<blockquote class="wp-embedded-content" data-secret="paBu4nyBJV">. 
<p>. <a href="https://tbwdrawingprize.artopps.co.uk/online- 
entry/">Online Entry</a></p></blockquote>
<p><iframe title="&#8220;Online Entry&#8221; &#8212; TBW Drawing 
Prize" class="wp-embedded-content" sandbox="allow-scripts" 
security="restricted" style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1px, 
1px, 1px, 1px);" src="https://tbwdrawingprize.artopps.co.uk/online- 
entry/embed/#?secret=paBu4nyBJV" data-secret="paBu4nyBJV" 
width="600" height="338" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" 
marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><embed style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"
```

https://adsler.co.uk/adsler-blog/

Comment: you mean strech the embed section?

Comment: Yes please..... So it fits ti desktop width proportionally.....

Comment: just set the width: 100%,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the iframe - the width is set to `600px` in the width attribute.
If you replace it to `100%` it will fill the width of the parent.

```
<iframe title="&#8220;Online Entry&#8221; &#8212; TBW Drawing 
Prize" class="wp-embedded-content" sandbox="allow-scripts" 
security="restricted" style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1px, 
1px, 1px, 1px);" src="https://tbwdrawingprize.artopps.co.uk/online- 
entry/embed/#?secret=paBu4nyBJV" data-secret="paBu4nyBJV" 
width="100%" height="338" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" 
marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

If you want to make the change universal to all of the `iframe` and `embed` tags, try the  following css

```
iframe, embed {
  width: 100% !important
}
```

Comment: But what about if I want to set all entries, embedded or not, to width 100%. How would i do it with css?

Comment: @One89 I've edited my comment to reflect what I believe you are asking.

Comment: Thanks, kinda.  But what about if I just wanna post a picture, for example?As in everything that goes on that page to be width: 100%. Will your code do that? Thanks

Comment: No, the css specifiers are for `iframes` and `embed` tags only. There are 2 ways to go about selecting everything inside the section, either add the tags to the css rule, such as `iframe, embed, img { width: 100% }`, or give the parent element an id or class, such as `.parent` then use `.parent > * { width: 100% }`. It selects all children of the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not misunderstanding your problem, you should just set width to 100%. I tried to edit it on the link you posted and it seems to fit the width of the screen well.

```
<div class="entry-content">
<blockquote class="wp-embedded-content" data-secret="paBu4nyBJV">. 
<p>. <a href="https://tbwdrawingprize.artopps.co.uk/online- 
entry/">Online Entry</a></p></blockquote>
<p><iframe title="&#8220;Online Entry&#8221; &#8212; TBW Drawing 
Prize" class="wp-embedded-content" sandbox="allow-scripts" 
security="restricted" style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1px, 
1px, 1px, 1px);" src="https://tbwdrawingprize.artopps.co.uk/online- 
entry/embed/#?secret=paBu4nyBJV" data-secret="paBu4nyBJV" 
width="100%" height="338" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" 
marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><embed style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have applied inline width style to your `embed` and `iframe` tags, as you can see here:

[image]

and

[image]

(From page inspect: Chrome Devtools)

Change these to `width:100%` and you'll be good to go! Cheers!